# node.js Is it possible to start server on existing unix socket file?

Tags: node.js, sockets, unix

`net.Server.listen` throws an error if being bound to an existing unix socket file. Is it possible to fix this without deleting the file first?

Or could I detect whether it's not used by another node process, if not - delete it, if it is - crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `net.connect()` to it first, if there's no one listening you'll get an ECONNREFUSED error.